# Loop show head of several data frames

Tags: r, lapply

I have several data frames and I would like to run the `head` function over all of them. I tried the following but it doesn’t work, as it returns the name of the data frame but not the head of the data frame itself.

```
df.a <- data.frame(col1 = "a", col2 = 1)
df.b <- data.frame(col1 = "b", col2 = 2)
df.c <- data.frame(col1 = "c", col2 = 3)

list <- ls()

for (i in 1:length(list())){
  head(list[i])
}

lapply(ls(),head)
```

Any idea on how to do it or why it is not working?

Comment: You need `lapply(mget(ls(pattern="df\\.")), head)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your data frames into a list, and add print to your loop.

```
my.list <- list(df.a, df.b, df.c)

for (i in seq_along(my.list)){
  print(head(my.list[[i]]))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

We need to get the value of the objects provided by the `ls()` as a `vector` of `character` strings.  If the object names have a `pattern`, specify the `pattern` in the `ls` and wrap it with `mget` to get the values in a `list`, loop over the `list` with `lapply` and get the `head`

```
lapply(mget(ls(pattern="df\\.")), head)
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun, I see that `mget` is the version of get that retrieves multiple variables at once. However, why do you use `pattern="df\\."`? Where does `df\\.` come from?

Comment: @user3507584  The `\\.` is for escaping the `.` in `df.a`, `df.b` etc. as `.` is a metacharacter which means any character